# Explanation for lambda in python

Tags: python, lambda

I'm a newbie in Data Analytics.
Can someone please explain the use of the lambda for counting x using lambda function.

```
specific_lambda=lambda x: set(['Adventure','Fantasy', 'Comedy','Drama']).issubset(x)
comic_movies=df[df.geners_arr.map(specific_lambda)]
comic_movies

count_lambda=lambda x: len(x)

df['Genre_count for Movie']=df.geners_arr.apply(count_lambda)
df.head(3)
```

Comment: You should start with what exactly you don't understand. The use of lambda for counting `x` using lambda function is - _counting `x` using lambda function_. That's literally what the English word "for" means - the use of something. Less trivially, if you are asking how we're doing it, `df.apply` takes a callable, and lambda is a callable.

Answer (score 0):

Lambda functions are anonymous functions. The following two are equivalent:

```
def count_lambda(x):
    return len(x)
```

is the same as

```
count_lambda = lambda x: len(x)
```

See also https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions